# How does HLSL handle clip(vector)?

Tags: opengl, directx, glsl, hlsl

My goal is to convert clip() to GLSL, version 1.5. I'm currently doing a basic:

```
if (x < 0) discard;
```

But if x is not a scalar, obviously I can't use the "<" operator.

So I'm wanting to understand exactly how HLSL treats a vector (or a matrix) in the clip function so I can account for those as well. Any resources would be much appreciated, as I couldn't find any detailed info about the function. Thank you!

Comment: You can specify custom clip planes with GLSL using [gl_ClipDistance](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/manglsl/xhtml/gl_ClipDistance.xml). [This link](http://github.prideout.net/clip-planes/) looks like a fine introduction to this feature of OpenGL.

Comment: That is a very good intro to the clip planes with glsl, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But if x is not a scalar, obviously I can't use the "<" operator.

You can simply do this:

```
if (x < 0 || y < 0 ) discard;
```

According to [clip(x) documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb204826%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (emphasis mine):

> Use the clip HLSL intrinsic function to simulate clipping planes if
>   **each component of the x** parameter represents the distance from a
>   plane.

According to the docs `x` could be a scalar a vector or a matrix.

Which means, if *any* of the components where less than zero it discards the pixel, this is true since if each of `x`,`y`,`z` represented a distance to a plane, this means than anyone of them being less than zero means the pixel should be clipped/discarded. Which makes the implementation boils down to the original form:

```
if (x < 0 || y < 0 || z < 0 ) discard;
```

but I will be surprised if the compiler was not able to detect this pattern and optimize by replacing it with it's appropriate assembly instruction.

Comment: Thank you for a great explanation. I had assumed that was the case, but I wanted to know for sure.